# how can I take lxc container backup

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, backup

I want to take lxc container backup. We have server with `12.04 LTS ubuntu server` and I have installed `LXC - 1.0.0.alpha2` in it. I wanted to update our ubuntu server to 14.04 LTS. So what I want to do is have LXC containers backed up -> upgrade OS to 14.04 -> restore LXC containers. With earlier version(0.7.5 I guess) there was lxc-backup and lxc-restore but with 1.0.0.alpha2 we don't have backup and restore operations. How can I have lxc containers backup. I spent more than 3 hours with copy container folder(/var/lib/lxc/my_container/) into pendrive and paste it in another 12.04 LTS server but it is not working the error am getting is,

```
#sudo lxc-start -n my_container
lxc-start: invalid sequence number 1, expected 4.
lxc-start: failed to spwan "my_container"
```

then how can I expect that it will work in upgraded 14.04 server OS.

Any Idea to have lxc-container backup?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've also posted this question to Stack Overflow, [the answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069385/643866) might apply here too.